# problem with double include of <string.h>

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, type-conversion

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Community. I'm working on an MFC dialog based project. I want to convert existing csv file to pdf, for this purpose I want to use Aspos.Cells library. problem is that when I include: #include <Aspose.Cells.h> since I already have this library included: #include "afxdialogex.h", I'm getting an error that CString type is ambiguous, and I think the problem is that there's a  double include from both of those files. Is there any way to fix it? is there preferable way to use comfortable interface for dialog based application such as MFC but on the other hand, one that let's me comfortably produce pdf files?

Thank you

Comment: Multiple includes of MFC/ATL or system headers is unlikely to be the cause of your error (those headers will have guards to address such issues). More likely is that the`Aspose.Cells.h` defines its *own* version of `CString`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for your answer, do you know if there is any way of solving this conflict? I've been trying to solve this for hours, but can't find any solution

Comment: The issue is your ODR violation. `CString` is not a type. It expands to either `CStringA` or `CStringW` depending on your environment. The *real* issue is that you are using `CString`. Stop doing that and your problems magically go away.

Answer (score 0):

As Adrian Mole mentioned, the problem indeed was that `Aspose.Cells.h` defines its own version of `CString`. What solved the problem for me was using `CStringW` as IInspectable mentioned. Thanks everyone!